# android custom font making the app to crash

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-fonts

It call a json file and shows data via RecyclerView.

I want use custom font in fragment.

this is the structure of XML.

**MainActivity.xml**
   ...

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/vp_horizontal_ntb"
```

...

**fragment_tab_2.xml**

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/main_recycler"
    ...
    tools:listitem="@layout/service_list"/>
```

**service_list.xml**

```
   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/movie_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is a title"/>
```

I do these steps:

I put the fonts in src/main/assets/fonts folder.

**fragment java:**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View x = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_2,null);

        TextView textView = (TextView) x.findViewById(R.id.movie_title);
        Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(textView.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/custom_sans.ttf");
        textView.setTypeface(face);
```

The app will be compiled but it crashed  when I run it on a device.

what is my mistake?

**log:**

```
04-05 06:11:11.237 30326-30326/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
04-05 06:11:11.298 30326-30339/com.test.teb E/HAL: load: id=gralloc != hmi->id=gralloc
04-05 06:11:11.315 30326-30326/com.test.teb W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.test.teb-2/lib/arm64
04-05 06:11:11.336 30326-30326/com.test.teb I/HwCust: Constructor found for class android.app.HwCustHwWallpaperManagerImpl
04-05 06:11:11.347 30326-30326/com.test.teb W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
04-05 06:11:11.509 30326-30326/com.test.teb I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
04-05 06:11:11.892 30326-30326/com.test.teb I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 30326 SIG: 9
```

Comment: please post crash log

Comment: That's not the stack trace from your crash. You're likely getting a `NullPointerException`, since you're looking for the `TextView` with ID `movie_title` in the `View` created from the `fragment_tab_2` layout, but it's not there. It's in the `service_list` layout. If that's the layout for your `RecyclerView` items, you need to set the typeface in the `Adapter`, not in the `Fragment`'s `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure TextView`(movie_title)` is exist in your fragment layout`(fragment_tab_2.xml)`.
2. In `Typeface.createFromAsset()`, use `getActivity().getAssets()` instead of `textView.getContext().getAssets()`

   ```
   Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/custom_sans.ttf");
   textView.setTypeface(face);
   ```
3. Use `inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_2, container, null)` instead of `inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_2, null)`.
4. Finally, from fragment `onCreateView()`, must return `View x`.

   ```
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View x = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_2, container, null);

       TextView textView = (TextView) x.findViewById(R.id.movie_title);

       Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/custom_sans.ttf");
       textView.setTypeface(face);

       ..........
       ...............

       return x;
   }
   ```

Hope this will help~